# How do I declare a custom char_traits<> for my own type?

Tags: c++, iostream, streambuf

I want to make a custom `char_traits` class for my own type. I have declared all the functions, but I am having some confusion regarding vague semantics given in the standard.

1. What are `fpos_type`, `off_type` and `state_type` expected to do? Where are they required, if at all?
2. Standard says to keep `traits::eof()` and valid code points separate and thus asks to use an `int_type` which is bigger than the `char_type`. But can I then make my `char_type` as a signed number where I know valid code points are only in the non-negative range. It leaves me with negative values as possible values of `traits::eof()`. Or should it be that `int_type` should be a proper superset of `char_type` so that no `char_type` can ever take the value of `eof()`? Being more to the point, can I make `int_type` and `char_type` to be same?

Answer (score 0):

1. `std::fpos` is a class that encapsulates file positioning semantics for file streams. It uses the current conversion state to identify file positions. `off_type` and `pos_type` are types defined in `std::char_traits` that are types for offset types and position types respectively. `pos_type` is used as arguments to seek functions and is the type returned from the tell functions. It is a type denoting absolute positions. `off_type` is used in the overloads of the seek functions for specifying offsets from a provided file position.

   `state_type` is also defined in `std::char_traits`. It is used for specifying the conversion state of a multibyte sequence.

   You can look up all the requirements for these types in `[char.traits.require]`.
2. This is the definition of `traits::int_type` - `[char.traits.typedef]`

   > ```
   > typedef INT_T int_type
   > ```
   >
   > For a certain character container type `char_type`, a related container type `INT_T` shall be a type or class which can represent all of the valid characters converted from the corresponding `char_type` values, as well as an end-of-file value, `eof()`. The type `int_type` represents a character container type which can hold end-of-file to be used as a return type of the iostream class member functions.

   This definition carries with it the implication that `int_type` merely be able to to represent values of type `char_type`, and also the `eof()` value. It defines no further requirements for the type other than what types it aliases for certain specializations of `std::char_traits`